# "uses" variable in CakePHP controller inheritance

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I have a problem using the public variable `uses` in the CakePHP controller.

I set up my application with the following schema.

`PagesController` extends an `AdminController` which extends the `AppController`:

```
class PagesController extends AdminController 
class AdminController extends AppController
```

I do this because I also got an `ApiController` instead of the `AdminController` which is used for an additional API layer in my application.

I include the additional layer by using

```
App::uses('AdminController', 'Controller');
```

in the `PagesController` and

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

in the `AdminController`.

It works fine for me this way.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $uses = array('Print');

}
```

I want to make a model called "Print" accessable in every of my child controllers.

That is why I initialize it in my `AppController`:

```
class PagesController extends AdminController {

    public $uses = array('Article');

}
```

In `PagesController` I want to use the "Print" model and in addition to that declared an "Article" model. In the commentary for that `$uses` variable it is written that every addition in the child controller will be merged into the parent `$uses` variable.
But it doesnt do. It overwrites it.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of difference to the question, but that's not a variable, it's a function / method call.

Comment: /**
 * An array containing the class names of models this controller uses.
 *
 
public $uses containing the table-Models set up in the Controller to use there
 * Example: `public $uses = array('Product', 'Post', 'Comment');`
 *
 
App::uses is just the static call to add additional php-Classes.

Comment: I really don't get your question but one thing to mention, Cakephp has a default `PagesController` with `public $uses = array();`. So, I think if you don't mention `public $uses` on your child controller it will take default `$uses`....

Comment: I just used the PagesController in my example here, in my code there are alot of other Controllers with the same problem.

Comment: you could use `$this->loadModel('Article')` in PagesController and will still be able to use `$this->Article`. I had the same issue and did a similar workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works ok:

`AppController.php`

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $uses = array('Print');
    public function test() {
        echo 'AppController => ';
    }
}
```

`AdminController.php`

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class AdminController extends AppController {
    public $uses = array('Photo');
    public function test() {
        parent::test();
        echo 'AdminController';
        if (is_subclass_of('AdminController', 'AppController')) {
            echo ' (Subclass of AppController)';
        }
        echo ' => ';
    }
}
```

`PagesController.php`

```
App::uses('AdminController', 'Controller');
class PagesController extends AdminController {
    public $uses = array('Article');
    public function test() {
        parent::test();
        echo 'PagesController';
        if (is_subclass_of('PagesController', 'AdminController')) {
            echo ' (Subclass of AdminController)';
        }
        if (is_subclass_of('PagesController', 'AppController')) {
            echo ' (Subclass of AppController)';
        }
    }
    public function index() {
        self::test();
        pr($this->uses);
        exit;
    }
}
```

`/pages/index`

```
AppController => AdminController (Subclass of AppController) => PagesController (Subclass of AdminController) (Subclass of AppController)
Array
(
    [0] => Article
    [1] => Print
)
```

`Cake` merges only with one controller (`AppController` by [default](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#538-588)), not all the way up (`AdminController->AppController->Controller`).
That's why there is no `Photo` model in `Pages`.

You can try to merge `$uses` from `Pages, Admin, App` (and any class between) like this:
`AppController.php`

```
protected function _mergeControllerVars() {
        parent::_mergeControllerVars();
        $parent = get_parent_class($this);
        while ($parent != 'Controller') {
            $parentVars = get_class_vars($parent);
            if (isset($parentVars['uses']) && $parentVars['uses'] !== true) {
                $this->uses = array_merge(
                    $this->uses,
                    array_diff($parentVars['uses'], $this->uses)
                );
            }
            $parent = get_parent_class($parent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aint you mean this why up? AppController->AdminController->Controller ?

Comment: Do you have any idea to merge those Models especialy used under adminController into the uses-variable?

Comment: I've added _mergeControllerVars to my answer but it needs testing.

Comment: This works great thanks alot. There's one problem doing the same with the "components". Those initialisations have to be done in the "initialize"-function not in the declaration, otherwise the merge aint work anymore properly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have syntax problem, can you try below solution. Please write following code in your controller:

```
public var  $uses = array('Print');
```

Comment: The var keyword has been deprecated since PHP 5.0, it has no functional use in PHP any longer and is only supported for backwards compatibility.

Comment: My friend i am using php version 5.4 and it is running in a good manner

Comment: Sir, it works, because it is left in to support old applications. It is no longer proper syntax and should not be used in new code. Please see the "Note" section under the Property Visibility heading on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php